# Test if images are loaded with casperjs

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs

I am trying to test whether images are loaded correctly on a page using casperjs. I am using this method - http://vgaltes.com/index.php/2013/03/16/testing-with-casperjs-part-2/, so in my script I have something like

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {        //checks if images are loaded
      var status = resource.status;
      if(status >= 400) {
         casper.log('Resource ' + resource.url + ' failed to load (' + status + ')', 'error');
         resourceErrors.push({
             url: resource.url,
             status: resource.status
         });
      }
});
```

It works for some pages, but sometimes I get the error (though in browser a page looks absolutely fine):

```
FAIL ReferenceError: Can't find variable: resourceErrors
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: ./test_new.js:120
#    error: Can't find variable: resourceErrors
#           ReferenceError: Can't find variable: resourceErrors
#               at ./test_new.js:120
#               at emit (/home/test/casperjs/modules/events.js:80)
#               at onResourceReceived (/home/test/casperjs/modules/casper.js:2594)
#    stack: not provided
```

Any ideas what causes this error?

Thanks

Comment: Show your complete script. Or just move the definition/initialization of `resourceErrors` to the top of the script.

Comment: I didn't really needed resourceErrors there at all. replaced it with this.test.fail('Resource ' + resource.url + ' failed to load (' + status + ')');